# Azure Data Factory - Copy Offce data to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, office365, azure-data-factory

Goal is to extract data from Offce 365 via Azure Data Factory into a SQL Server.
It seems like that it is only possible to sink the data from an Office source into the following technologies:

Azure Copy Object:

[image: Azure Copy Object]

Sinks für Offce Source:

[image: Sinks für Offce Source]

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can only [copy data from Office 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-office-365?tabs=data-factory) to  Azure Blob Storage, Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1, and Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 in JSON format.

You can copy data to blob storage using a copy activity first and then connect it to another copy activity to copy from storage to the [SQL server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server?tabs=data-factory).

Comment: Hey @Dnegelof, had it solved your problem? else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding you need to select dataset as binary format when configuring source and sink.
So the sink presents with the Binary format sources:

[image]

So 1st step would be to copy the data into blob as a file and then copy from file into SQL